# ORACLE SQL Query - AVG

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database

So I have the following Oracle SQL Database table:

```
create table Customer
(customerID char(25) not null, 
name char(50), 
address char(100), 
dateRegistered DATE, 
noOfDvdHiring int, 
primary key (customerID));
```

And I have the following query: List the unique numbers and names of all customers who are hiring more DVDs than the average number of DVDs currently hired by all customers.

I'm sure this should involve a nested query but I am unsure where to start?

I have tried:

```
SELECT customerID, name
FROM Customer
WHERE noOfDvdHire > AVG(noOfDvdHire);
```

But receive this error message:     ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT customerID, name
FROM Customer
WHERE noOfDvdHiring > (select AVG(noOfDvdHiring) from customer);
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that would work but I receive this: 
 ORA-00904: "NOOFDVDHIRE": invalid identifier

Comment: the actual column name is `noofdvdhiring`. changed it.

Comment: If possible can you help with me another query I have?

Comment: sure..but post it as a different question

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes I believe

Comment: sure..then..what is your question?

Comment: I have the following query: Find the unique numbers and names of all directors who have never directed a science fiction film. I have tried:

    SELECT DISTINCT directorName, Director.directorID 
    FROM Director, Film 
    WHERE Director.directorID = Film.directorID AND filmCategory  <> 'science fiction';

But that just lists all of the Directors (I have tried != as well)

Comment: try this. `SELECT d.directorName, d.directorID 
    FROM Director d 
    where not exists (
    select 1 from Film f where d.directorID = f.directorID 
    and f.filmCategory = 'science fiction')`

Answer (score 0):

2 ways... the difference is in execution plans

```
select * from (
  select customer_id, noOfDvdHire, avg(noOfDvdHire) over () avgg from Customer
) where noOfDvdHire > avgg

select customer_id, noOfDvdHire from Customer
  where noOfDvdHire >  (select AVG(noOfDvdHire) from customer);
```

Comment: Thank you, for both ways I get the following error: 
 ORA-00904: "NOOFDVDHIRE": invalid identifier